# What does "getline > 0" in AWK mean?

Tags: redirect, awk

I see this awk idiom all the time and I would like to know exactly what it means

```
while (getline <"FILE" > 0)
```

I understand what getline is doing, but I don't get redirection to 0.

According to [The Awk Programming Language](https://ia802309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf), you do this to avoid a infinite loop in the case of FILE being nonexistant.

Why does redirection get rid of that error? What exactly is being redirected? It can't be the return value of getline, otherwise, what expression is while evaluating? I'm missing something!

**EDIT:** Thanks for the comments. I got redirection operators confused with relational operators. Perhaps it would be clearer if it was written like this

```
while ((getline <"FILE") > 0)
```

Or even clearer

```
while (0 < (getline <"FILE"))
```

Comment: It would be better if you post what you like to do, and some data files.  This solution may be change to some like: `awk 'FNR==NR{do some;next} {do some more}' FILE otherdata`

Comment: Thanks jotne. I answered my own question. The syntax threw my mind for a loop

Comment: I just say that it may be another solution (better?) to use standard input for `awk` instead of reading it using a `while` loop and `getline`, by using `FNR==NR`

Comment: You should read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>` sign is testing the return value from `getline` (for greater than zero). It is not a redirection sign.
From  https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html :

> The getline command returns one if it finds a record and zero if it
>   encounters the end of the file. If there is some error in getting a
>   record, such as a file that cannot be opened, then getline returns -1.
>   In this case, gawk sets the variable ERRNO to a string describing the
>   error that occurred.

The confusion may come from the fact that output redirection to a file is not used by `getline`. (It is  used only to read data). So there should be no ambiguity regarding the `>` sign. (It cannot mean output redirection)
To print something to a file you can use output redirection from the `print` or `printf` commands.

Comment: I understand what getline is doing, and i've read the manual. What does the >0 mean?

Comment: @captaincurrie It compares the return value of `getline` with the number 0. So if `getline` finds the record (return value = 1), it continues to read records in the `while` loop..

Comment: @captaincurrie If number is larger than `0`, continue to run the while loop.

Comment: OHHHHH!!!! Jesus. Well that is obvious. All these redirection operators got me so confused. That makes complete sense. Thanks guys!

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thanks for clarifying your answer!